# Python 3 with Selenium: Getting local variable 'element' referenced before assignment

Tags: local, attributeerror

I have created conftest fixture in different conftest.py file which includes driver initialization with driver as global.

Below is the code

---

driver = None

@pytest.fixture()
def setup_And_teardown(request):
global driver

```
options = chromeOptions()
prefs = {'download.default_directory': StrDownloadedFilesPath}
options.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=chromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
   
StrURL = GenericUtilites.Read_Configuration("config", "basic_info", "url")
driver.get(StrURL)
driver.maximize_window()
intImplicitWait = int(GenericUtilites.Read_Configuration("config", "basic_info", "ImplicitWait").strip())
driver.implicitly_wait(intImplicitWait)
request.cls.driver = driver
yield
driver.quit()
```

---

Then i have created two two python files such as ObjectInteractionUtilites , Login and User
ObjectInteractionUtilites  : I have all basic interactions methods in this Python File

class OIU:

```
def __init__(self, driver):
    self.driver = driver

def EnterText(self, strIdentificationTechnique, strObjectReference, strInput):
    -------------------------------
   --------------------------
def Click(self, strIdentificationTechnique, strObjectReference):
    -------------------------------
   --------------------------
```

Login : Have created functions for login and Different Menu Navigations with help of
ObjectInteractionUtilites  functions

```
def __init__(self, driver):
    self.driver = driver
```

Created function for Navigation
def Navigation_To_Different_Modules(self,strMainMenu,StrSubMenu):
match strMainMenu:
case "ABC":
OIU.Click(self, strIdentificationTechnique, strObjectReference):
case "XYZ":
OIU.Click(self, strIdentificationTechnique, strObjectReference):

User: Created User related functions.

```
def __init__(self, driver):
    self.driver = driver
```

def UserCreation(self): # Here i have navigation function inside user creation function
Login.Navigation_To_Different_Modules(self,mainMenu,submenu)

problem 1 :
Here is the problem is when i execute test cases i am getting local variable 'element' referenced before assignment
problem 2 :
Getting  AttributeError: 'Test' object has no attribute 'GetElement'
Steps I have created common function to get element and passed GetElement function in different function ( SendText) .. Note : SendText and GetElement are present in same python file.

---

```
def GetElement(self,strIdentificationTechnique,strObjectReference):

    match strIdentificationTechnique:
        case "NAME":
            element = self.driver.find_element(By.NAME, strObjectReference)
        case "CSS":
            element = self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, strObjectReference)
        case "XPATH":
            element = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, strObjectReference)
        case "ID":
            element = self.driver.find_element(By.ID, strObjectReference)
        case "CLASS_NAME":
            element = self.driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, strObjectReference)
        case "LINE_TEXT":
            element = self.driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, strObjectReference)
        case "PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT":
            element = self.driver.find_element(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, strObjectReference)
        case "TAG_NAME":
            element = self.driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, strObjectReference)
    return element
```

---

```
def SendText(self, strIdentificationTechnique, strObjectReference, strInput):
    Ele= self.GetElement(self,strIdentificationTechnique,strObjectReference)
    Ele.send_keys(strInput)
```

---

Could you please help

I have tried with removing driver as global